# Atooma plugin stops working

Tags: android, atooma

I made a simple plugin for Atooma: performer plugin to change a wallpaper photo upon trigger: Screen On. After it triggered this action couple of times after some time it stopped working: in Atooma notification it always says that it has been triggered but my performer doesn't get called: I made sure by putting couple of log calls inside performer.
I checked the logs and these may provide some clue:

```
threadid=17 (Thread-6653): calling run()
android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    at com.atooma.plugin.r.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.atooma.plugin.z.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.atooma.engine.t.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
threadid=17: exiting
```

This log message appears every time when trigger is activated ('screen on' in my current case)

Another symptom is that when I look at my task in Atooma, I don't see DO part where my performer action was - no icons, after DO nothing shows (description bellow is ok). When I try to edit it - Atooma crashes: dialog message appears: "Unfortunately, Atooma has stopped. Report/Ok". If I click OK  Atooma obviously get restarted showing me again my task, icons for my performer are still missing but when I click edit it works this time. Performer again works upon trigger but after a while it stops working again with same exceptions as above listing from log every time it gets triggered.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I saw the same problem. It happens when the Atooma service died or something internal to Atooma happens (the plug communicates with Atooma via aidl remote service). The only option is to uninstall and install the plug again. Report this behavior to the Atooma team.

Comment: I asked them on support email but no answer yet. And you don't have to reinstall it - just restart Atooma app which happens automatically since it crashes when I try to edit my task for a first time... :)